# Why do i have to pre-style a input field in CSS before implementing that style by through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently following a form validation tutorial in which i am creating a sign up form. I want the border of the input field and the icon to turn green if the information  that is typed in by the user meets the input fields criteria and turn red if it does not, exactly like the picture below.

[image]

Here is the code for the "Username" input field.

```css
.form-control.success input {
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.form-control .success i.fa-check-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
  <div class="form-control success" >
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username"
          placeholder="Enter username..." id="username">
          <!-- Awesome fonts -->
          <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
```

My instructor pre styled the input fields in CSS before he even worked on the Javascript file. My question is that why does it have to be pre styled in CSS, can't you just leave the input field normal and if the condition is met use Javascript to turn the input field green.

Comment: you mean this Form_validation =>  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation ?

Comment: how are you going to use javascript to make it green? That comes from css

Comment: pre-style  just for a standard input, javascript can change the class to show a green border

Comment: @HansC.FelixRamos Sorry i might sound stupid but why does you have to pre style for the  standard input. Why cant you just leave the input field as it is and then change the class to show a green border Javascript?

 Sorry if it looks like I am asking the same question again, i'm new to this and i just think it is extra effort pre styling it in CSS.

Comment: That might work fine for one page, but imagine a website where you may have many pages. You want everything to look uniform, so you put it in a style sheet and just apply styles using JavaScript. That way if you change anything you can be certain that you’ve changed it correctly across the entire site and not just on one page.

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes.

Comment: John is right. The whole point of the CSS file is for consistently and reuseability.

Comment: in this case color validation is designed by css `input:valid {...` and`input:invalid {...`  with browser default colors, you can change them as you whish, no need of javascript for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to style form inputs conditions .
The most basic is to change every style on tags that you want to change . I show you what exactly I mean .

```
function correctInput(elem) {
  elem.querySelector("input").style.borderColor = "#2ecc71";
  elem.querySelector("i.fa-check-circle").style.visibility= "visible";
  elem.querySelector("i.fa-check-circle").style.color = "#2ecc71";
}
```

In this way you are changing styles with `javascript` only . But the technique that your instructor used is much smarter . In this technique you use `javascript` and `CSS` together .

```
function correctInput(elem) {
  elem.setAttribute("class", "success");
}
```

Now you see the difference . In the `CSS` you will style your `div` block and children with every single condition that you want to have in your inputs . Then you only change the `class` name of the `div` block with `javascript` then `CSS` will do the rest for you .